# javascript regex help latex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to detect `\(` but not `\\(` in javascript

Also I want to replace it with `~~\(`

What is wrong with the following code `replace(/(?!\\)\\\(/g, '~~\\\(')` ?

(This is mathjax latex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?!\\)\\
```

Is a bit of a contradiction. "*The next character must not be a `\`, then match a `\` as the next character.*"

Since JavaScript doesn't currently support look-behinds, you can capture a negative character group and just put it back into the string:

```
replace(/(^|[^\\])\\\(/g, '$1~~\\(')
```

The `^|` allows it to also match at the beginning of the string since the `[^\\]` alone would require a leading character.